# Issue with Chrome + CSS3 Transform + BG Image

Tags: css, google-chrome, transform

I'm having an issue in Chrome where an element that has Y offset using CSS3 transform affects the position of the next element that has a BG image. The BG image gets pushed by the previous element.

P.S. When the elements don't have relative position the bug isn't there, but in this case I do need the relative position.

[The BUG example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dczEm)

Answer (score 0):

**Update 2:**
First try adding-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden; to your div with the background image. If the problem persists, you need to remove position:relative; from this div.

<s>**Update:**</s>

If you are referring to the black space above the photo... that's part of the photo. Otherwise, it looks fine in chrome. The top of the image is at the top of the div.

Try absolute positioning. Using relative leaves a 'ghost' behind of that element. So when you modify it's position, it moves the element where it's visible, but it also affects where it WOULD normally be in the structure.

Comment: Thanks, but I need them to be relative in this case. And just gave it a try, it seems the same bug is happening even when they're absolute.

Comment: In my late night debugging last night I made a "little" mistake which led me to wrong conclusions, bloody image. I updated the example now with the CORRECT bug.

Comment: Seems codepen won't allow me to update the code, made a new one, updated the link.

Comment: Sorry for wasting your time, this issue threw me out of balance. Please if you can give it a check ( link updated )